# Visual Studio debugging issue - Debugger pointing unrelated code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

### **I have issue debugging the Specflow- BDD automation tests writen in C#. Issue is below:**

When I right click on the test from the test explorer and select Debug Test option. Ironically, the debugger is pointing to some other location on the code, which is no where related to the current test or methods used in it. And also, safe to mention it always points to one particular file and line every time every time I try to debug. This is inconsistent, I delete the bin and clean build and if restart the VS19. Then the issue goes off... Any suggestion?
I am using - VS19, Specflow for VS2019.

Answer (score 0):

Do a clean and rebuild-all on your solution.

When you see that in the debugger, it means that the code is stale. Sometimes from test projects, they pull in assemblies which have helper assemblies that do not necessarily build when the test project (or those assemblies) change when debugging/running from the test project. So do a build all.